# Trouble creating an actively responsive grid layout

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to design a website using the grid breaking layout. I want to make responsive columns, that listen and respond to scroll events and the like. I think i have it mostly figured out but i couldn't make my grids respond to scroll movements, like what happens on the front page of [vrarlesfestival.com](https://www.vrarlesfestival.com/). If you can see how the bar with the menu button and letters of the large text moves when you scroll, that's what i'd like to do.

I'm thinking i could make individual letters of the large test with the CSS:before > '*content*' function, styled into individual HTML sub classes for each of the letters?

Then, the bar that moves when you scroll - so far i only have just the bar. I don't know how to make the scroll motion decrease its height to a certain level, before actually scrolling the whole window down.

these are HTML and CSS snippets of where i am at this moment...

```css
.edge-panel {
  background-color: #eee;
  width: 20%;
  height: 301.5vh;
}

.menu-bar {
  background-color: #23252b;
  width: 30%;
  height: 75vh;
  position: sticky;
  margin-left: 70%;
  margin-top: 150px;
  top: 0;
  transform: translateX(30%);
  transition: height 1s ease-in-out;
}

.menu-bar:hover {
  border: 5px solid #eee;
  transition: .2s ease-in-out border;
}
```

```html
<div class="edge-panel">
  site name here
  <div class="menu-bar">
    menu here
  </div>
</div>
```

[that dark straight thing is the bar i am focusing on](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9CCLV.png)

My target,for now, is the menu bar, i would like to have it decrease height when i scroll. Once the height would have reached a certain level, then the window can start moving down, and vice-versa for when i scroll back up, like in [vrarlesfestival.com](https://www.vrarlesfestival.com/). If you have some insights on the individual letters moving as well, i'd appreciate those too.
Anyone who can help??
ps. I am familiar with vanilla JS, i just don't know how to apply it here, for this task.

Comment: I believe this stuff is done using Three.js

Comment: @UmbQbify I've inspected the linked website in DevTools and I see that the menu bar and individual letters movement do not use Three.js.

Comment: I can't think of any other way but to have `scroll` event , and checking scroll position, OR  using an intersection observer on the whole containing element, the latter one could be tricky

Comment: Yes i tried using an intersection observer and adding classes `hidden` and `show` to the menu bar, but i can't seem to get the show function going: `const observer = new IntersectionObserver((entries) => {
  entries.forEach((entry) =>{
    console.log(entry)
    if (entry.isIntersecting){
      entry.target.classList.add('show');
    } else {
      entry.target.classList.remove('show');
    }
  });
});

const hiddenElements = document.querySelectorAll('hidden');
hiddenElements.forEach((el) => observer.observe(el));
`

Comment: i gave the `show` and `hide` classes their own attributes which i believe to be okay. i then added the hidden class `<div class="menu-bar hidden">` to the intended element, but it only acts as far as hiding the element. Bringing back and removing the `show` class is not working

Comment: But @UmbQbify, Three.js might work. In time